# Kubernetes master offline scenarios

Tags: kubernetes, master-slave

So I have two hypervisors running the following Kubernetes VMs:

A) 1x K8s master, 1x k8s node

B) 1x K8s node

If hypervisor B goes offline, all pods still work, as designed. What happens to the cluster and the nodes when hypervisor A goes offline? Will all running pods on the hypervisor B K8s node still work, assuming I have node anti-affinity configured so that on every node at least one pod already runs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pods will keep running and will restart if they crash but the API will not be available so it will not be possible to run anything new or change them.

Comment: This is just partially true: a lot of infrastructure level components depend on API and if it's unavailable for too long - they will start dying too (eg etcd at least recently could not tolerate missing API for minutes).

Comment: If you mean etcd for the cluster, that would generally be running on the control plane "node" as well so it would also be very down if the host is offline :)

Comment: In that case having the pods running on an alone worker node makes even less use :-) I think it should be noted in the answer, so that OP didn't think that having the control plane node would lead them anywhere.

Comment: Yes, very +1 for this being a bad thing to do. Do not run Kubernetes like this for anything other than personal learning lab.